# Are Indizations cocomplete

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathcal{C}$ is an essentially small category, is it true that $Ind(\mathcal{C})$, the full subcategory of $Fun(\mathcal{C},Set^{op})$ consisting of functors which can be expressed as filtered colimits of representable ones, is closed under small colimits?

I think that it should be equivalent to be closed under equalizers, since $Ind(\mathcal{C})$ is closed under filtered colimits, and hence under coproducts.

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: This category is more properly called the "ind-completion of $\mathcal{C}$".

Comment: If $\mathcal{C}$ admits finite colimits, then $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ admits small colimits, see Proposition 6.1.18 of the book "Categories and sheaves" of M. Kashiwara and P. Schapira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the category $\mathbf{Set}_{10}$ of sets of order at most $10$. This category has all filtered colimits but is not cocomplete (it does not contain the coproduct of two sets of order ten).

Comment: You are right; So we also should pose the question of finite coproducts for $Ind(\mathcal{C})$.